# Within Where Clause, Nested Case When Statement to return Result with 'OR'

Tags: t-sql, nested, ssms

Good afternoon everyone,

I am trying to combine 2 separate function to create a semi-dynamic where clause. Currently I have 3 identical view in my SQL database which are pretty much the same except for the following line pending on what the user state are.

For WA User.
`(dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'CDS' )`

For VIC User.
`(dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'VIC' OR dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'WA')`

For NSW User.
`(dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'NSW')`

Therefore, if the user is from NSW, return results from their user state.. and if the user is from WA then return result where ProcessState is CDS and if the user is from VIC then return result where ProcessState is either VIC or WA.

I have written the following nested case when statement to try and combine these 3 views into 1:

```
    `dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 
    (CASE 
    WHEN dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'NSW' THEN 'NSW' 
    WHEN dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'WA' THEN 'CDS' 
    WHEN dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'VIC' THEN 'VIC OR WA' 
    END)`
```

This seems to be working perfectly fine for both NSW and WA users but when I trial it as a VIC user, it returns nothing. I suspect it could be a syntax issue but i have tried the following without much success:

Have tried to use:('VIC OR WA'), ('VIC' OR 'WA'), ['VIC' OR 'WA'], <'VIC' OR 'WA'>

Hoping that someone more knowledgeable is able to show me what it is I am missing or even suggest a better way to complete this dynamic statement. Many many thanks in advance!!

SeanY

Comment: hi HABO, my colleague and I created the SQL database and we know that the column only have the following values. NSW, VIC, WA and CDS. Previously user belonging to each state will only require value from their respective state but due to recent changes they now require results from other state and sometimes a combination of 2 states. so I am trying to filter ProcessState to return results with both 'WA' and 'VIC' for VIC users,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'VIC OR WA'` is literally "VIC OR WA", that is why there are no rows returning.
`dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState` would have to equal "VIC OR WA" (this exact/literal string) to return rows.

What you want instead `dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState IN ('VIC','WA')`

So there is an element of dynamic SQL involved in order to have your `CASE` statement return exactly what you need.

Comment: I will try to come up with the logic to help you with this.

Comment: OMG thanks Brien, I have tried looking everywhere online for resources to assist but unable to find any information for this. The function can also be written differently to facilitate BUT I've only just started learning TSQL recently and my repertoire of functions/statements are quite limited :(

Comment: @HABO has a better answer. Eliminates the need for the dynamic sql query building, and appears to be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Brien is close. This should do the trick:

```
case
  when dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'NSW' and
    dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'NSW' then 1
  when dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState = 'CDS' and
    dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'WA' then 1
  when dbo.JunctionT.ProcessState in ( 'VIC', 'WA' ) and
    dbo.fnGetReviewState(CURRENT_USER) = 'VIC' then 1
  else 0
  end = 1
```

Comment: I am having travel navigating the statement but will give it a whirl! I can kinda understand how you wrote this... but with my current skill level I don't think I would have been able to pull this off myself!! Thanks Much HABO!

Comment: OMG IT WORKS! I have been *Face Palming* and literally *Banging my head on the table* for almost 1 day! ...thank you guys very much for saving me from doing permanent damage to my head!